# jquery css change not working against inline CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

For some reason the WordPress theme I am using is injecting inline `CSS` without a source. I figure I try and change the `CSS` using `jQuery`. When I use the console it works once, and then goes back to the inline after hovering over the pseudo `a:hover` selector. Also, when I add the code to the theme, it doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    jQuery('.et_pb_widget_area .et_pb_widget a').css({"color":"#0099cc"});
});
```

I'm fairly new to jQuery, but I can't find the answer cause I am still not sure of the syntax.

Comment: are the styles you added removed after you hover again?

Comment: Yes! So when I hover, it defaults back to the inline styling and ignores jQuery

Comment: Interesting. So they may be clearing out the inline styling (which is what you are adding to) and re-adding the default styles on whatever that action is . You may have better luck using css with the important attribute

Comment: I tried that, but the inline style has an !important attribute attached, which is the killer... That's the reason why I am trying to use jQuery to override it. Inline styling right? Humbug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should ensure that not only will jQuery reset the color when the document first loads, but later, even when the respective elements are hovered over, jQuery will maintain the `color` as `#0099cc`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.et_pb_widget_area .et_pb_widget a').css({"color":"#0099cc"});

    jQuery('.et_pb_widget_area .et_pb_widget a').hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).css({"color":"#0099cc"});
    });

});
```

Comment: I looked at in the console and after the hover the console returned $ is not a function. I wrote jQuery instead and returned the same error. The site is futures.uts.edu.au if that helps?

Comment: Ah, OK, I changed the $ to jQuery, then added the same classes above and it worked!!! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Updated - I should have spotted that! Glad it worked for you.